# How to show success message if data is fetched successfully in console.log?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stripe-payments

I am using stripe library in react-native, I am getting data in `console.log` successfully, but I want to redirect to another page if it's success, or if it has any error then show on page. I've tried to redirect to another page but it's redirecting even it has an error or not, I don't know how to do this. I've tried to do it like this..

Here is my code:

```
payme() {
        const apiKey = '<api_key>';
        const client = new Stripe(apiKey);
        client.createToken({
            number: this.state.number,
            exp_month: this.state.expmonth,
            exp_year: this.state.expyear,
            cvc: this.state.cvc,
        }).then((x) => {
                let successmsg = x;
                NavigationService.navigate('LoginPage');
        }).catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
        })
    }

render() {
        return (
          <Text>{this.successmsg}</Text>
        )
}
```

[image]

Can anyone help me about how can I show the error and how can I redirect to other page only on success.

Comment: where is this. successmsg() ??

Comment: Use `this.setState({ response: x })` and use the state in the render function `{this.state.response}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your code you will get error in this.successmsg

```
    state = {
     successmsg : null          
    }

    async payme() {
            try{
                   const apiKey = '<api_key>';
                   await result  = new Stripe(apiKey).createToken({
                   number: this.state.number,
                   exp_month: this.state.expmonth,
                   exp_year: this.state.expyear,
                   cvc: this.state.cvc,
                   })

                   if(!result.error){
                      //do your success logic
                     //set your successmsg based on reslut object option
                      this.setState({successmsg : "YOURCUSTOM MESSAGE FROM RESULT OBJECT"})
                      NavigationService.navigate('LoginPage');

                   } else {
                      // throw your error here
                        throw "something went wrong"
                    }

             }
             catch(e){
              throw new Error(e);
             }

        }

    render() {
            return (
              <Text>{this.successmsg}</Text>
            )
    }
```

Comment: it's showing me the error in if(result){this.setState({})}...  it's error place

Comment: check the screenshot above in code. I did console in if(result){}

Comment: what is the status code your using from server... if you use 200 that is the place you got your error response.

Comment: means? i didn't get it that status code using from server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192019/discussion-between-sathish-kumar-and-zain-shabir).